# 'await` has no effect, its return undefined

Tags: javascript

Simply I want to return JSON response using `fetch` in `data-source.js`, but why can't I use `async/await` in `main.js` in order to wait for the *return*?

> I understand that `async/await` will not wait for the *return*, because it is waiting for a *promise*. But, what should I do to make it wait for the response?

**data-source.js**

```
import clubs from './clubs.js';

class DataSource{
    static searchClub(keyword) {
        const baseUrl = `https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1`;
        fetch(`${baseUrl}/searchteams.php?t=${keyword}`)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(responseJson => {
            if(responseJson.error) {
                return responseJson.error;
            } else {
                return responseJson;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return(error.message);
        });
    }
}

export default DataSource;
```

**main.js**

```
import DataSource from '../data/data-source.js';
import '../component/club-list.js';

const main = () => {
    const searchElement = document.querySelector("search-bar");
    const clubListElement = document.querySelector("club-list");

    const onButtonSearchClicked = async () => {
        try{
            const result = await DataSource.searchClub(searchElement.value);
            renderResult(result);
        } catch (message) {
            fallbackResult(message)
        }
    };

    const renderResult = results => {
        clubListElement.clubs = results;
    };

    const fallbackResult = message => {
        clubListElement.renderError(message);
    };

    searchElement.clickEvent = onButtonSearchClicked;
};

export default main;
```

Thank you for your response.

Comment: What is the clubs property on the clubsListElement? Are they custom elements?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes it is

Comment: searchClub returns nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return the promise in your searchClub function

```
return fetch(`${baseUrl}/searchteams.php?t=${keyword}`)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
```

Edited to explain better:

You said:

> I understand that async/await will not wait for the return, because it
> is waiting for a promise. But, what should I do to make it wait for
> the response?

This is correct, it will wait for the promise...which was never returned from the function...so it didn't wait.

The http fetch always gets fired inside your searchClub function. If you would've logged out the response before - it would've logged out the correct response.

```
fetch(`${baseUrl}/searchteams.php?t=${keyword}`)
    .then(response => {
        console.log('i can see this')
        return response.json();
    })
```

But the function searchClub wasn't returning anything, it was just making a http request and since that request wasn't returned, nobody could wait for it. Since nobody could wait for the promise, nobody could use the actual data the promise would return.

You can google "the promise chain" - you return the promise, and the promise will return the data (or another promise). You can't get the data until the promise has finished/resolved.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am really new to API things. Don't even understand to returning the response.

Comment: Glad I could help. I added a little more explaination that might explain return the response better. If you're happy with my answer/solution I would greatly appreciate if you could mark it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
static async searchClub(keyword) {
   try{

    const baseUrl = `https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1`;
    const response  =  await fetch(`${baseUrl}/searchteams.php?t=${keyword}`)
    const responseJSON = await response.json();

    return responseJSON
   }catch(error){
    return error.message
   }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Seems that `await` before `await response.json()` is not needed.